# Reading in from a text file, with character limit

Tags: java

I am trying to read in text from a text file, it's supposed to read in every word delimited by just a space(i.e ignore everything else).

so for now, i am reading in every word from the scanner and adding it to a list. Then i am trying to add from list to SecondarrayList only if the number of characters added to the Secondarylist doesn't exist 100 characters.

Yes i am trying to iterate the first List, and make sure every word that can fit under 100 characters fits under the limit in each list and doesn't add word mid way or break up words

i ran this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < SecondarrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(SecondarrayList.get(i));
        }
```

but not thing happens :/

```
    Scanner input = null;
        try {
            input = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> SecondarrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

        String word = null;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            word = input.next();
            // System.out.println(word);
            list.add(word + " ");

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            // System.out.println(list.get(i));

            do {
                SecondarrayList.add(list.get(i));

            } while (findlenghtofListinChars(SecondarrayList) < 100);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SecondarrayList.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(SecondarrayList.get(i));
        }

    }

}

// returns number of length of chars
public static int findlenghtofListinChars(ArrayList<String> arrayL) {

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayL.size(); i++) {
        // System.out.print(arrayL.get(i));

        str = str.append(arrayL.get(i));

    }

    return str.length();

}
```

The sample output when prints word(also we can ignore "," "/" all the others as well just delimted by space)

```
small 
donations 
($1 
to 
$5,000) 
are 
particularly 
important 
to 
maintaining 
tax 
exempt
```

Comment: can you include the output when you uncomment the // System.out.println(word); part?

Comment: Wow, that is some creative code (: Please specify: what is your ambition? From your description and code I understand you want to read the first 100 characters from a text file. Is that right?

Comment: Yes i am trying to iterate the first List, and make sure every word that can fit under 100 characters fits under the limit in each list and doesn't add word mid way or break up words

Comment: Why there is two list? can do it using one List.

Comment: if you can that be great, no specfic need for 2 list

Comment: Amal posted an answer. what about that? working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I think you want to do something like this :

```
 Scanner input = null;
  try {
      input = new Scanner(new File(file));
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> SecondarrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

  String word = null;
  while (input.hasNext()) {
      word = input.next();
      list.add(word);
  }

  int totalSize = 0;

  for (String eachString : list) {

        totalSize +=eachString.length();

        if(totalSize >=100){
            break;
        }else{
          SecondarrayList.add(eachString);
        }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < SecondarrayList.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println(SecondarrayList.get(i));
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the problem with your code is that you are using a while loop whose condition is always true.

This is because the input that you gave it has a character length of ~80 which will always be <100

For this reason I suggest changing the while loop of yours to become an if statement, e.g.

```
do {
    SecondarrayList.add(list.get(i));
} while (findlenghtofListinChars(SecondarrayList) < 100);
```

will become

```
if(findlenghtofListinChars(SecondarrayList) < 100){
    SecondarrayList.add(list.get(i);
}else{
    break;
}
```

Comment: I am aware this is similar to the other answer, but I believe that it helps you understand the problem more if you are explained what to do rather than just being thrown a block of code